# Are there any reports that K-2SO will return?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

K-2SO was working on the communication when he 'died'. Since he was programmed with a bit of a 'self preserving' character, is it possible that he embedded his programming in the outgoing messages?

In other words, **have there been any reports that he will reappear in another Star Wars movie**?

Comment: I heavily edited your question to make it less subjective and more in accordance with Movies.SE policies. If you disagree, edit it back, at the risk of having your question closed for being too opinionated.

Comment: It's my understanding that Rogue One was "A Star Wars story".  It was meant to be a stand-alone movie to enhance and fill in gaps in the overall story, as it took place between Episodes 3 and 4.  Being that they're now on Episode 8, I don't see how or why they'd bring a character back after such a lengthy absence, unless they were to write yet another "Star Wars story" and fill in gaps elsewhere.

Comment: @BlueMoon93 +1 Thanks for putting down my words more clearly. I try to uphold policies, but sometimes it's difficult to find the words.

Comment: @JohnnyBones That would be plausible. Why not? R2 has the plans of the original death-star and maybe (unknowingly) have K-2SO's personality code too. When he ever inserts his sticky thingy into another K-model robot it will upload... ta-da: K-2SO

Comment: Because we already know, from R2's personality in the original trilogy, that he doesn't.  Why would he suddenly start acting like K-S20 40 years later?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Not saying R2D2 would do that at all. But that if R2 connects to another suitable robot, the dormant personality of K-2SO could then be uploaded to the other robot.

Answer (score 5):

Alan Tudyk [mentioned](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/rogue-one-alan-tudyk-his-star-wars-future-951547) the possibility of going back to the past in an interview in December 2016:

> **Do you think we’ll see K-2SO in any other installments?**
>
> I’m doing my best. (Laughs) Sure, why not? All these worlds are intertwined. It’s exciting to me what they’re doing with these stand-alones. You can criss-cross those timelines at any point. They’re creating them. They’re giving these backstories to characters and filling in blank spots like ours.

More recently, he's [stated](http://uproxx.com/movies/alan-tudyk-k2so-rogue-one/2/) that he won't appear in the Han Solo spin-off film:

> **The Han Solo movie takes place before Star Wars and before Rogue One. So with these movies that are set before Rogue One, we could see K-2SO pop up, right?**
>
> I would like it. I don’t think it’s possible, because I think they’re done with the Han Solo one, aren’t they?
>
> **Oh, no. They just started filming.**
>
> They just started? That would be cool.
>
> **I’m not saying you’re in that one, I’m just saying maybe in the future…**
>
> No, I want to be in that one, man.

Comment: But no rumors of him appearing in any stories or main story-line that takes place after the events on Scarif?

Comment: The top quote seems to imply that you _might_ get a *backstory*, rather than a follow on from events of Rogue One. I'm sure rumors will come out in good time though!